# Java removing an iterator that removes another element in the same list

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` called blocks that is iterated through using an iterator. Before i call the `.remove()` method of the current iterator i must remove another object in the list that is linked to the object being removed. An attempt to do this results in a concurrent modification exception as expected. Do you know how i could work around this? Sample code:

```
for (Iterator<Block> iterator = Blocks.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Block block = (Block) iterator.next();
    if (block.getX() == x && block.getY() == y) {
        block.remove(); //This removes another block from this list but throws the error
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the iterator to continue removing more elements after the first match? Or are you just trying to remove the first match?

Comment: Just the first match, it only happens once.

Comment: You basically get that exception because you'd confuse the iterator which might lead to hard to find bugs. Thus you'd have to either do it with the iterator only or collect the blocks to remove and then remove them after the loop (e.g. by using `blocks.removeAll( blocksToRemove )`). - However, this sounds like some sort of game so the design might not be fitting, i.e. instead of linked blocks you might be better off using a different structure.

Comment: This is a good solution thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to remove the first match, then the simplest solution would be to iterate through the list to find the first match and save that match in a variable that can be accessed outside of the iterator loop. Then just break out of the loop and perform the cleanup (removal) needed

```
Block removeMe;
for (Iterator<Block> iterator = Blocks.iterator();  iterator.hasNext();) {
        Block block = (Block) iterator.next();
        if (block.getX() == x && block.getY() == y) {
            removeMe = block; 
            iterator.remove();
            break;
        }
}
removeMe.remove();
```

Comment: This is what i got from Thomas' comment and it works perfectly thanks!